# Lazy load web-components from other services in polymer 3

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I have a microservice based application and each service has a set of polymer based web-components. I want to load these at runtime in the application that is served by one of them at runtime, so that I can run, maintain and deploy the services seperately.
I would like to avoid having a npm repo that serves the components for a central build and each new web component version would make it necessary to rebuild and redeploy the application.

Existing lazy loading examples all lazy load components of the same application, so it's built as a whole and just packaged in chunks.

The application is available under /app/ and the modules are under /mod/...

I can do this in to react to a route:

```
import('/mod/admindashboard/kw-admindashboard.js').then((module) => {
  // Put code in here that you want to run every time when
  // navigating to view1 after my-view1.js is loaded.
  console.log("Loaded admindashboard");
});
```

and then I can use the corresponding web component, but for this to work I need to hack the component like this:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '/app/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '/app/node_modules/@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js';
import '/app/node_modules/@polymer/iron-icons/iron-icons.js';

class KwAdmindashboard extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
...
```

But this approach prevents me completely to run tests, create static builds and IDE support is not available either in many areas, as it's not able to see what is available later at runtime. So as absolute fallback this would be possible. Isn't there a way to utilize the serviceWorkers to handle mapping?

Comment: Since you keep update your question, I believe you will find your answer soon but one thing I want to share based on my experience (not much) I would prefer to have a private npm repo for each component. In this way you can easily manage version for each component in each application. This is obviously separate build not central. And also If you separate build each component and then import you may end up with a lot of duplicate dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I played around and managed to come this far, now I'm stuck for sure, as I'm leaving my experience that I built up with polymer 1 before. The single build would be a way that enables a nicer development eperience for sure, and with versioned components in my own nexus-npm repo I have a chance to have a controllable workflow. But web-components should be able to support my desired flow as well. Otherwise it's still just a fancy way to load modules if everything needs to be present at build time an no real "late binding" is possible.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. At first glance, I think you want to create a service like private unpkg to serve your private components and used by multiple applications. But you said "The application is available under /app/ and the modules are under /mod/" so this is a single application and their dependencies is in the same repo?

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to load a module dynamically when you navigated to the page. and load module with this page' s label or name?

Comment: @User28 Sorry, I didn't express the usecase well enough.
 /app and /mod/$SERVICE are the URLs where the artefacts are accessible. The services are located in their own git repos.

Comment: @HakanC, Yes I try to dynamically load modules/web-components that are built seperately

Comment: Here below I will try to  add an example which I inspired from shop-app before It was 2.x and I will try to convert it 3.0 version

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen If you serve each services with esm, everything should work fine with dynamic import. If you have to transpile it to non-module for support old browser, you have to separate build self-contained for each services then import it with dynamic import as usual. You can use url like `http://repo.../dist/index.js` or use some prefix like `/mod` then proxy it from nginx or whatever. You can do integration test as usual but IDE support it will be impossible.

Comment: @User28 no that doesn't work because the webcomponents would be served individually, so Webcomponent 1 would fetch a dependency from its node_modules and another webcomponent would fetch it from his, which would clash, because you can't load the same components twice. The workaround I use forces deduplication by referencing a common "location" for dependencies, but this breaks all IDE support and unit-testability due to "weird" imports that are only resolvable at runtime.

Comment: Oh you're right. I forgot that part. Now I think I just understand your example code. What about serve those components like other your components? like `/mod/...iron-icon.js` in this case all of components which import this will have the same path and execute only once.

Comment: As I wrote, I can use absolute import statements, which works in the browser, but completely breaks all local stuff like static builds, tests, IDE support etc. Basically it weould be neat to have a way to keep the regular imports, but influence the way it's loaded in the browser to just fetch everything from node_modules from a central place even when it was in different dirs at built/deveopment time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Polymer 3 is not yet ready for distributed locations of webcomponents.

There are github issues at the W3C which may solve these problems:

- https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/716 
  Web component registries for really distributed component development without clashes due to namespaced component registration
- https://github.com/domenic/import-maps 
  introduces a mapping from "nopm module names" to locations, which enables runtime binding much easier

For now I will switch my development model, so the microservices provide one or more webcomponents to my npm repo in nexus and the admin app has build time dependencies to them and builds the whole app in one go and there I can use the lazy loading approach that the shop demo also promotes/shows.

For a decent development experience with webcomponents from multiple sources, you should have a look at ["npm link"](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Feel free to add another solution for the problem or a real solution as soon as the technology and standards caught up.

Answer (score 1):

Here below is I think a good example of your requirement. Modules will be loaded with page properties. As page property is depended on iron-page, `selected='{{page}}'` when page value has been changed with iron-page's name properties, its observer loads the that page's modules. :

```
static get properties() { return {
    page: {
      type: String,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      observer: '_pageChanged'
    },
.......

_pageChanged(page, oldPage) {
    if (page != null) {
      let cb = this._pageLoaded.bind(this, Boolean(oldPage));

     // HERE BELOW YOUR PAGE NAMES
      switch (page) {
        case 'list':
          import('./shop-list.js').then(cb);
          break;
        case 'detail':
          import('./shop-detail.js').then(cb);
          break;
        case 'cart':
          import('./shop-cart.js').then(cb);
          break;
        case 'checkout':
          import('./shop-checkout.js').then(cb);
          break;
        default:
          this._pageLoaded(Boolean(oldPage));
      }
```

here above `cb` is a function which is loading lazy modules but needs to load immediately after the first render. Which is minimum required files.

```
_pageLoaded(shouldResetLayout) {
    this._ensureLazyLoaded();

}
```

Here the full code's link of the above. Hope this helps In case of any question I will try to reply. https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/master/src/shop-app.js

Comment: Thank you, I had a look at the shop example before, as I wrote these examples only work because the whole shop is built in one directory and depencencies are all resolved at build time. I think that web-components aren't ready yet for a truely distributed deployment due to (presumably) the missing feature to resolve the dependencies to modules at runtime.